# Detect if material design animation has ended in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can i detect if the animation of  (or any other) has ended. Is there a built in approach in angular? The only thing i can register is that it is expanded, opened or closed. But these properties are triggered immediatly after selecting the panel. But i have to wait until the animation ends OR (better) trigger code while the animation renders!

I've implemented the cdkObserver but it only observes if the content has changed, not if the animation has ended.

Answer (score 0):

For instance for the sidenav, just by **[going into the "API" tab and looking for a couple of seconds](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api#directives)**, you can find this :

```
@Output()
openedStart: Observable<void>       Event emitted when the drawer has started opening.
```

I'm pretty sure you can find every other hook into the documentation.

And if they're not there then you can't hook on animations.

Comment: Of course i've looked into the API. But there is no way to detect the "expansion panel" animation. But thank you for your answers. I think i have to implement a quick and dirty solution.